# Close Tkinter window with button only if all variables have been set

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter version of a questionnaire, where each question is multiple choice (using radio buttons). I want to only be able to close the window if all of the questions have been answered. Is there a way to do this? Nothing I've found on the site has touched on conditional buttons.
Currently, my button closes the window no matter what and my code looks like this:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk


class Questionnaire(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.vsb.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
        self.initUI()

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, "units")

    def initUI(self):
        """ question and instructions are just lists of strings """
        all_questions = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        answers = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_1 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_2 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_3 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_4 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        Instructs = [[] for _ in range(len(instructions))]
        self.parent.title("Questionnaire")
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")

        self.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
        r = 0
        for i in range(len(instructions)):
            Instructs[i] = Tkinter.Label(self.frame, text=instructions[i]).grid(row=r, column=1)
            r += 1

        for i in range(len(all_questions)):
            all_questions[i] = Tkinter.Label(self.frame, text=question[i])
            all_questions[i].grid(row=r, column=1, columnspan=8)

            answers[i] = Tkinter.IntVar()
            button_1[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="1", variable=answers[i], value=1)
            button_1[i].grid(row=r, column=9)
            button_2[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="2", variable=answers[i], value=2)
            button_2[i].grid(row=r, column=10)
            button_3[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="3", variable=answers[i], value=3)
            button_3[i].grid(row=r, column=11)
            button_4[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="4", variable=answers[i], value=4)
            button_4[i].grid(row=r, column=12)
            r += 1

        Submit = Tkinter.Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command=self.close_window)
        Submit.grid(row=r, column=11, columnspan=2)

        self.mainloop()
        self.answers = [ans.get() for ans in answers]

    def close_window(self):
        self.parent.destroy()


root=Tkinter.Tk()
app = Questionnaire(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you tried adding some conditional code in your `close_window` method?

Comment: Yes, I passed in answers and had "if 0 not in [ans.get() for ans in answers]: self.parent.destroy(), but that didn't work (I assume because the conditional must be evaluated before the variables?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1. Everywhere use `self.answers` instead `answers`
2. Remove `self.mainloop()` from `initUI` method

Worked code:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk


class Questionnaire(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.vsb.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
        self.initUI()

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, "units")

    def initUI(self):
        question=['q1','q2','q3','q4']
        instructions=['i1','i2','i3','i4']
        all_questions = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        self.answers = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_1 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_2 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_3 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        button_4 = [[] for _ in range(len(question))]
        Instructs = [[] for _ in range(len(instructions))]
        self.parent.title("Questionnaire")
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")

        self.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

        r = 0
        for i in range(len(instructions)):
            Instructs[i] = Tkinter.Label(self.frame, text=instructions[i]).grid(row=r, column=1)
            r += 1

        for i in range(len(all_questions)):
            all_questions[i] = Tkinter.Label(self.frame, text=question[i])
            all_questions[i].grid(row=r, column=1, columnspan=8)

            self.answers[i] = Tkinter.IntVar()
            button_1[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="1", variable=self.answers[i], value=1)
            button_1[i].grid(row=r, column=9)
            button_2[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="2", variable=self.answers[i], value=2)
            button_2[i].grid(row=r, column=10)
            button_3[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="3", variable=self.answers[i], value=3)
            button_3[i].grid(row=r, column=11)
            button_4[i] = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.frame, text="4", variable=self.answers[i], value=4)
            button_4[i].grid(row=r, column=12)
            r += 1

        Submit = Tkinter.Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command=self.close_window)
        Submit.grid(row=r, column=11, columnspan=2)


    def close_window(self):
        if 0 not in [ans.get() for ans in self.answers]: self.parent.destroy()


root=Tkinter.Tk()
app = Questionnaire(root)
root.mainloop()
```